# WSO2 API Manager Log creating an API

Tags: api, logging, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Can someone please explain to me how to log when an API has been created in WSO2 API Manager v1.9.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable debug log in api manager to see the log when API is created.

Go to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties` file and add the following line

```
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl=DEBUG
```

and restart the server you can see log when api created as below
ex:

```
DEBUG - APIProviderImpl API Name: WeatherAPI, API Version 1.0.0 created
```